# Rspec expect specific record instance to receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails model `User` with an attribute `age`.

I want to test that some code alerts any users who are over 25.

I have this test writen:

```
    it 'sends an alert to users over 25' do
      user_who_should_be_alerted = User.create(age: 26)
      user_who_should_not_be_alerted = User.create(age: 19)

      expect(user_who_should_be_alerted).to receive(:alert_user)
      expect(user_who_should_not_be_alerted).not_to receive(:alert_user)

      alert_users_over_25
    end
```

Of course this doesn't work since `alert_users_over_25` will create new objects by querying the database. It won't use the ones created in the test.

The closest I have come up with is:

```
    it 'sends an alert to users over 25' do
      user_who_should_be_alerted = User.create(age: 26)
      user_who_should_not_be_alerted = User.create(age: 19)

      expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:alert_user).once

      alert_users_over_25
    end
```

This mostly works, but I don't explicitly say which user should be alerted, so it could pass if it only notifies `user_who_should_not_be_alerted`.

My other option is to create a single user aged 19 then run `alert_users_over_25` and expect nobody to be alerted. Then in another test create a user aged 26 and expect the opposite. Again though, this seems less bullet proof since I am not testing how it works when there are multiple users in the database. It also seems less clear. I think the first test gets across what the method is supposed to do much better than the other option.

My question is, what's the cleanest way to implement this test so that it ensures `alert_users_over_25` will call `alert_user` for the user who is 26, but not the user who is 19?

Comment: The best way is to test what actually happens when a user is alerted - not the fact that some code happens to call `.alert_user` on that instance. For example does it spool an email, create a job, make some kind of notification record in the database or alter the user record? It may seem obvious but test the behavior, not the implementation.

Comment: @max Yeah that makes sense, I still haven't implemented that bit yet (or decided what it will do). I saw that as the responsibility of `alert_user` which I was going to test once I implement it. I don't care that `alert_users_over_25` sends an email, just that it tells my user model that it should alert the user. Then when I implement `alert_user` I can say that it should send an email or whatever I decided at that point. That way if I ever decide that alerting users shouldn't send an email but instead should send a smoke signal, I don't need to update my tests for `alert_users_over_25`

Comment: A "better" way to solve this is to use a service object or ActiveJob which avoids adding more responibilities to your model. The would let you to do something like `expect(UserNotifier).to recieve(:perform).with(user: user)`.

Comment: Hmm yeah I think that's a lot better. I'll probably end up doing that. Thanks :) I think that solves my issue but I still think my question is valid for other concerns, say `alert_user` was instead `update_fields` which should update the users records depending on some conditions. In that case `update_fields` would still belong in the User class. In that case my question would still be valid. But you are right. For my particular issue I will just extract the user alerting functionality to somewhere else

Comment: In that case I would check for the database transformations `expect do; User.update_all(name: 'Mr Potato Head');  user.reload; end.to change(user, :name).to 'Mr Potato Head'`.

Answer (score 0):

The code has two responsibilities that can be tested separately

1. Find out which users need alerting
2. Call alert_user for those users.

You can create two methods for these two things. lets say User.alertable_users and User.alert_necessary_users. alert_necessary_users will call alertable_users and call alert_user for those users.

In the test cases of second method, you can

```
allow(User).to_receive(:alertable_users) { [user_who_should_be_alerted] }
expect(user_who_should_be_alerted).to receive(:alert_user)
```

Notice that the structure has become more single responsibility principle oriented. If your logic of alertable_user changes from those above 25 to something else, then your test cases for the 2nd method do not change!